# internal implementation of random()

Tags: math, random, lua

This is syntax for generating random numbers in Lua language--

math.random()

Almost all programming languages have this function with similar syntax.My question is how the function is implemented.how is it able to generate a randomized output?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source for the function?

Comment: It uses functions from standard C library (`rand` or `random` on POSIX systems). As Etan mentioned, you may look yourself as Lua sources are freely available.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pseudo-random algorithm works by producing a seemingly arbitrary pattern of bits from an existing seed value. The produced value is then kept as seed for the next random number.

Most random generators are initially seeded with a value from the system clock. Although the time is a relatively predictable value, it's random enough (for most applications) once it has passed through the random algorithm once.

The algorithm produces a series of seemingly unrelated values, so they can be used as random values. As there naturally is a relation between the values, even if it is very complex, the values are actually pseudo-random.

---

A simple random algorithm, that was used when computers where slower and machine words smaller, is to multiply the seed value with a prime number, add one, and get the lower bits needed for a machine word. Example (C#):

```
static ushort seed = 42; 

public static ushort random() {
  seed = (ushort)(seed * 8747 + 1);
  return seed;
}
```

The function returns these values the first 100 times that it is called:

```
39695  2438 25987 29442 38231 41886 30603 35418 12575 24118 65299 24114
30311 37198 50203 34442 60719  5350  3747  7010 40311 16638 42667 46266
 3903 60822 54323 27282 19079 29358 24379 54506 55119 43078 36803  3010
48535 58974 11723 42778 34143  1270 33107 48882 13991 23566 21083 60234
22895 50086 59619 17442 62903 37822  3307 24954 37759 42070  1651 23378
15047 19822 40315 51626 29583 26374  6659 50306 17879 18718 17419 58330
14751 52150 25491 16306 22247 18126 16539 28682  9647 37478  8995 36066
44535  1662 54059 11834 30655 31510 39091 27666 35591 18478 15291 56938
28623 17862  1091 40258
```

As you see, even such a simple algorithm gives pretty good results. Modern random generators however use more complex algorithms, like the [Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister).